# Routing traffic to single instance Elasticbeanstalk environment using Route 53

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have a python application installed under Elastic beanstalk environment and I want to setup ssl certificates for this single instance. Since I dont have registered domain to get an ssl what I am trying
is creating an domain alias under Route53 so I can have a consistent domain name for ssl. But my route alias is not redirecting traffic to Elastic beanstalk environment url.

My environment url is something like: `flaskapp-env.eba-xxxxxx.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`

I created a Hosted Zone Record named: `flaskapp.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com`, then under this Hosted Zone, I created alias record set  as:  `dev.flaskapp.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com` with alias target set to my elastic beanstalk environment.

I was expecting that the alias `dev.flaskapp.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com` should resolve to `flaskapp-env.eba-xxxxxx.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com` but that is not the case. I am not sure if this is even possible, please enlighten me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since I dont have registered domain to get an ssl what I am trying is creating an domain alias under Route53 so I can have a consistent domain name for ssl.

To setup a SSL certificate you need a **domain that you control**. The `elasticbeanstalk.com` is managed by AWS and you cannot create a hosted zone for that, as the domain is not yours. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingHostedZone.html):

> You can create a hosted zone only for a domain that you have permission to administer. Typically, this means that **you own the domain**, but you might also be developing an application for the domain registrant.

If you want an ssl without your own domain, you can setup **CloudFront distribution** in front of your Elastic Beanstaslk:

- [Using Elastic Beanstalk with Amazon CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudfront.html)

Comment: thanks for the doc link, CloudFront seems a wide subject can you provide a link to specific ?

Comment: I think you mean sth like this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https-cloudfront-to-custom-origin.html